# How to proof the limit is convergent for arbitrary initial state?

Tags: analysis

$\{a_n\},\{b_n\},\{c_n\},\{d_n\}$ is series.
And $d_n=c_{n-1},c_n=b_{n-1},b_n=a_{n-1},a_n=b_{n-1}+c_{n-1}$

how to proof for any $a_0,b_0,c_0,d_0$ belong to $Z^+$, $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty} \dfrac{(a_n-a_{n-1})}{a_{n-1}}$  is existent?

In fact,for any $a_0,b_0,c_0,d_0$ belong to $Z-\{0\}$,the result is right.

It is equal to :

for any $a_0,a_1$ belong to $Z-\{0\}$,$a_n=a_{n-2}+a_{n-3}$,$\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty} \dfrac{(a_n-a_{n-1})}{a_{n-1}}$  is existent?

Comment: The real problem is to translate all these to the language of $\{a_i\}$ :3

Comment: I have translated it ,but I still don't know to proof it.

Comment: Do you know the theory of linear recurrences? Note: You will also need the starting value $a_2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let the roots of $ x^3 - x - 1 = 0 $ be $ \alpha, \beta, \gamma$. Let $ \alpha$ be the real root. Note that $ |\alpha | > 1 $ and $ |\beta| = |\gamma| < 1$. From the theory of linear recurrences, we get that

$$ a_n = A \alpha^n + B \beta^n + C \gamma^n.$$

**Hint:** Show that if $ A \neq 0$, we have:

$$ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{ a_n - a_{n-1} } { a_{n-1} } = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{ A \alpha^n - A \alpha^{n-1} } { A \alpha ^{n-1} } = \alpha - 1.$$

**Hint:** Deal with the case when $A = 0$.

Comment: Can you give me some information about linear recurrences?I don't know it,it is apart of complex analysis? Can you speak Chinese?

Comment: @lanse2pty [Here you go](https://brilliant.org/discussions/thread/recurrence-relations/). It is part of combinatorics, though used in many disciplines of math.

Comment: @ Calvin Lin   Great,the linear recurrences is very useful.Do you have any result of your question that why  must all solutions be of this (seemingly exponential) form?